# Set position of windows that contain a word

Tags: windows, macos, applescript, move

I'd like to move the windows of a particular app to determined coordinates.

I have made a little raw script but I'd like to have it in a more elegant and functional way. It should only move windows that contain a determined word in their title. Maybe we should create a list of windows with a that word in the title and then cycle through them to put at those coordinates.

How can I achieve that?

That's what I've written so far:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "AppIT"
        (*
    {804, 368}
{536, 368}
{268, 368}
{0, 368}
{804, 22}
{536, 22}
{268, 22}
{0, 22}
*)
        set position of window 1 to {0, 22}
        set position of window 2 to {268, 22}
        set position of window 3 to {536, 22}
        set position of window 4 to {804, 22}
        set position of window 5 to {0, 368}
        set position of window 6 to {268, 368}
        set position of window 7 to {536, 368}
        set position of window 8 to {804, 368}

        set position of window 9 to {0, 22}
        set position of window 10 to {268, 22}
        set position of window 11 to {536, 22}
        set position of window 12 to {804, 22}
        set position of window 13 to {0, 368}
        set position of window 14 to {268, 368}
        set position of window 15 to {536, 368}
        set position of window 16 to {804, 368}

        set position of window 17 to {0, 22}
        set position of window 18 to {268, 22}
        set position of window 19 to {536, 22}
        set position of window 20 to {804, 22}
        set position of window 21 to {0, 368}
        set position of window 22 to {268, 368}
        set position of window 23 to {536, 368}
        set position of window 24 to {804, 368}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TextEdit"
        set w to windows where title contains "text"
        set position of item 1 of w to {0, 22}
        set position of item 2 of w to {268, 22}
    end tell
end tell
```